# prooving the harmonic inequality

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

My real analysis textbook shows this result but gives no proof for it, it would be great if someone could show me why the following result holds.

> Show
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n}{n(n+1)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
>  \frac{1}{n^{2}}$$
>
> where $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} 1/k$.

Comment: inequality or equality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using $\sum_{n\ge1}\sum_{k=1}^na_{nk}=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{n\ge k}a_{nk}$, the sum is$$\sum_{n\ge1}\left(\frac1n-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k=\sum_{k\ge1}\frac1k\sum_{n\ge k}\left(\frac1n-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=\sum_{k\ge1}\frac1k\frac1k.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} H_n \left ( \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{1+n} \right)$$
$H_n=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1-x^n}{1-x} dx.$
So $$ S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}  (t^{n-1} -t^{n})~dx~dt=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-t}{1-x} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (t^{n-1}-(tx)^{n}t^{-1})$$
$$S=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-t}{1-x}  \frac{1-x)}{(1-x)(1-xt)} dt dx=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1-xt} dt dx =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} x^nt^n dx dt.$$
$$\implies S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$$